# Upon loading JTable dynamically, before selected JComboBox appears visible

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I use:

- Java 10 SE
- Java Swing
- Eclipse IDE

I have JTable, the contents gets loaded at runtime dynamically. It has some JComboBoxes. If I select the JComboBox, and then attempt to reload the table, the JComboBox appears visible at the time when the table loading is in progress.

Besides that, if the JComboBox's contents gets updated (elsewhere in different table, when the combo  supposed to reflect that new contents), that new contents does not get visible staright away after loading the JTable dynamically.

The snap-shot sample of the app:
[image]

That's, the table being loaded at runtime up, and in the middle you have vsisble JComboBox persistent from the previous selection.

**How to:**

- Get rid off that persistent JComboBox
- Make the data visible instantly, upon update under the combo, once you load the table dynamically

I have the `public final class TableColumnEditor extends DefaultCellEditor{`
which returns the JComboBox on a specific column:

```
else if(row == ROW_2_DEVS_WORK_WEEKEND) {
            ProjectMetrics metrics = new ProjectMetrics();
            JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>();
            combo.setBackground(Color.WHITE);   

            for(String devs : metrics.identifyDevsThatWorkAtWeekend()) {
                combo.addItem(devs);
            }

            return combo;
        }
```

I have the `public final class TableColumnRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{`
which makes sure that the view displays the JComboBox under that specific column:

```
else if(row == ROW_2_DEVS_WORK_WEEKEND) {
            ProjectMetrics metrics = new ProjectMetrics();
            JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>();
            combo.setBackground(Color.WHITE);   

            for(String devs : metrics.identifyDevsThatWorkAtWeekend()) {
                combo.addItem(devs);
                break;
            }

            return combo;
        }
```

The table gets loaded dynamically right here (**non-essential things removed**):

```
public static void reloadTableDynamically(JTable metricsTable){

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)metricsTable.getModel();

    if(projectData.isEmpty()) {         
        metricsTable.clearSelection();

        int rowCount = model.getRowCount();
        for(int item = (rowCount - 1); item >= 0; item--) {
            model.removeRow(item);//clears previous rows    
        }

        metricsTable.repaint();                                 
        return; 
    }

    model.getDataVector().clear();      
    int rowCount = constantRows + ((devsTask.size() == 0) ? 1 : devsTask.size());

    try {
        new Thread(()-> {   
            int lastRowID = 0;
            int devsTaskID = 0;

            for(int item = 0; item < rowCount; item++) {                                        
                Object[] input = null;
                if(item == 0) {
                    input = new Object[] {"", metrics.getProjectDateRange(), "" };
                }//similar branches removed
                else {
                    devsTaskID++;
                    input = new Object[] {"", devsTask.get(devsTaskID).getDeveloper(), ""};
                }

                model.addRow(input);
                metricsTable.scrollRectToVisible(new java.awt.Rectangle(metricsTable.getCellRect(lastRowID++, 0, true)));
                metricsTable.repaint();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(Config.getInstance().getReloadInOutTable());
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            metricsTable.scrollRectToVisible(new java.awt.Rectangle(metricsTable.getCellRect(projectData.size() - 1, 0, true)));
            metricsTable.repaint();//so that to reach the last row

        }).start();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: ***"non-essential things removed"*** For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). (Note that though I normally only *recommend* people post runnable code, in this case it is *essential* for me to be tempted to look into this more closely.)

Comment: I get this issue, described above, each time I make the JTable loadable at run-time. Nuts-and-bolts have been provided above. Follow the same structure, please. Otherwise, what may cause such defect, in your opinion, please?

Comment: *Nuts-and-bolts have been provided above* - I don't understand your verbal description of the problem. I can't copy/paste/compile/test the code so I can't see the described behaviour, so there is no much I can do. Comments are to read the following sections from the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) on; 1) `How to Use Tables`. There is no reason to extend the DefaultCellEditor to use a JComboBox as the editor. The tutorial shows the proper way to do it. 2) `Concurrency in Swing`. Swing components should be updated on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out how to overcome this problem.
Firstly, the **JComboBox** gets updated on **EDT**(**Event Despatch Thread**).

```
/**
 * @param combo The JComboBox ref.
 * @param toDisplay The value to add to it
 */
public static void updateComboBoxOnEventDespatchThread(JComboBox<String> combo, String toDisplay) {
    Runnable doComboUpdate = new Runnable() {
         public void run() { 
             combo.addItem(toDisplay);
         }
     };

     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doComboUpdate);
}
```

Under the JTable column editor:

```
else if(row == ROW_2_DEVS_WORK_WEEKEND) {
            ProjectMetrics metrics = new ProjectMetrics();

            JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>();
            combo.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

            Runnable doComboInsert = new Runnable() {
                public void run() { 
                    int id = 0;
                    for(String devs : metrics.identifyDevsThatWorkAtWeekend()) {
                        UIutils.updateComboBoxOnEventDespatchThread(combo, "("+ ++id +") " + devs);
                    }                           
                }
            };

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doComboInsert);
            return combo; 
        }
```

But the main fix, without which both issues do not go away, is following.
That is, I noticed that in order for data to appear under the table instantly, firstly, you need to select any other unrelated table's cell.

That is, the Java thread, which loads the JTable at runtime, does need to have this:

```
if(model.getRowCount() > 0) {
        metricsTable.selectAll();
    }
```

That's probably a hack, but it works for me!